# How do you determine correct debconf-set-selections, I am interested in exim specifically, but would like to know the general way

Tags: exim, debconf

I need to configure exim non interactively but I'm having trouble determining the question answer key value pairs.

I would like to know how to find this info on other packages as they come up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a test install manually with the options you want, then check what was set:

```
debconf-get-selections | grep exim
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I just needed to run:
apt-get install debconf-utils
first.